Razorpay Popup Not Reappearing After First Close in React Integration
I have integrated Razorpay into my React project using the react-razorpay hook. The initial opening of the Razorpay payment popup works as expected. However, if the popup is closed and I attempt to reopen it by triggering the same action (e.g., clicking a button), the popup does not reappear.
As a workaround, I found that a full page reload (window.location.reload()) makes the popup reappear upon the next trigger. However, this solution is not viable for the user experience I aim to provide. I am looking for a way to reopen the razor-pay payment popup without needing to refresh the page.
